# You have a nil object when you didn't expect it (Appointments page)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, null, appointment

Okay so I am creating an appointments site for professors and students to log on and create/edit appointments. I have the professors side done but I am struggling with the students. Right now I am trying to make it so students click a button next to their appointment to remove themselves from the appointment that they have with a professor. Now I could easily just delete the appointment id and the appointment would be gone but instead I want to remove the student_id from the appointment so other students could choose that appointment later. here is my code:
THE CONTROLLER:

```
def destroy   
if session[:professor] != nil

    @appointment = Appointment.find(params[:id])
    @appointment.destroy
end
if session[:student] != nil
@appointment = Appointment.find_by_id_and_student_id(params[:id],params[:student_id])
@appointment.destroy(params[:student_id])  
end
end
```

VIEW:

```
<% @appointments.each do |appointment| %>
<tr>
<td><%= appointment.professor_id %></td>
<td><%= appointment.student_id %></td>
<td><%= appointment.timeslot %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'remove appointment', appointment, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method:  
:delete %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

I have included the link here with my files if you want to take a look.
[CLICK HERE TO VIEW MY FILES.](https://rapidshare.com/files/2992851703/hwfinal_wood.zip)
Also, everything takes place in the appointments controller. and this problem is in the show student view(where you press the delete button).

SOLUTION:
Okay so I got it working due to the help I got from you guys. So here is what I did:
@appointment = Appointment.find_by_id_and_student_id(params[:id], session[:student].user_id) 
@appointment.update_attribute(:student_id, nil)

Comment: Which of those lines does the error occur on?

Comment: app/controllers/appointments_controller.rb:118:in `destroy'

Comment: That doesn't help know what line it is in the code you've provided as it doesn't have any reference to line numbers. Add a comment in the code pointing out the line.

Comment: Sorry, wasnt thinking. the line is actually 116 AND is @appointment.destroy(params[:student_id])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost certainly the error here is that Appointment.find_by_id_and_student_id is returning nil. Refactor your code like this:

```
@appointment = Appointment.find_by_id_and_student_id(params[:id],params[:student_id])
if @appointment
  @appointment.destroy(params[:student_id])
else
  flash[:error] = 'An appointment could not be found for that student.'
end
```

This will prevent you from receiving that error and should help you track down its root cause.

Comment: The error is in the line: @appointment.destroy(params[:student_id])

Comment: Yes, but presumably the error is that ```@appointment``` is nil. So you need to correct that on the line you assign ```@appointment```. If it isn't, then you need to post the backtrace for your error.

Comment: Also if you have to pass an argument to `destroy` it means that `appointment` is not a single model object, but a collection.

Comment: sorry forgot to delete that line. Okay so now it just refresh's the page and does NOT delete the student_id. But at least it is now reading the student_id. just not deleting it from the appointment.

Comment: Yeah, that's not the appropriate syntax to delete the student_id from the appointment. You should use ```@appointment.update_attribute(:student_id, nil)```. And even so, if your page is rendering now then most likely the @appointment is still nil. Ensure that an appointment with that ID and student ID actually exists.

Comment: okay So in the database the id for appointment = 5 and the student is jtest so there is def an appointment there in the database. You are right, the student_id is read is null. my comment above i said it was reading student_id. i was wrong about that. So it is null (but not in the database) i just need to figure out a way to read the student_id value.